# Why code inside if loop is not executing even when condition is true?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

I am fetching json data from server using ajax in every 8 second . it work  fine most of the time but sometime  code inside 2nd if loop is not executing even when condition is true.

```js
setInterval(function () {
  if (board.turn != board.mycolor) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'checkgamedata.php',
      success: function (result) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);

        if (players[board.turn].lastturnno < obj.turnno) {
          //Code inside this if loop is not executing

          players[board.turn].lastturnno = obj.turnno;

          for (var i = dataleft; i < obj.kodidata.length; i++) {
            numbergot = grandom(obj.kodidata[i]);

            process(numbergot);

            if (obj.indexarr[i] != 'null') {
              updatepawn(obj.indexarr[i]);
            }
          } //For loop end

          if (board.turn != board.mycolor) {
            dataleft = obj.kodidata.length;
          } else {
            dataleft = 0;
          }
        }
        //If loop end
      } //Success end
    });
  }
  //Post end here
}, 8000);
//timeout end here
```

My result of ajax operation is something like this `{"kodidata":[["0.33","0.40","0.36","0.76"]],"indexarr":["2"],"turnno":"12"}`.

I checked value of obj.turn and players[board.turn].lastturnno just before if loop by using alert and i can see that obj.turn value is greater but still code inside if loop is not executing .why?

Comment: Hope you know that "null" is not the same as null.

Comment: I know "null" is not same as null but its nothing to do with it. My problem is that code inside if loop is not even seen to execute . @aditya

Comment: As @yousef mentioned, in the if condition where you are comparing lastturnno with obj.turnno. The obj.turnno is recvd as a string. Make the necessary type conversions for successful comparison as it returns a false if "12" is compared with 12 . Either change both to number or both to string.

Comment: @aditya thanks i will check whatever you pointed out .lets see if it work

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik _if "12" is compared with 12_ this will return `true` until you use `===`

Comment: Thts exactly what i meant @abhishek, thanks for pointing that out. Since we r talking abt type checks tht's evident

Comment: @aditya thank you so much .your comment really helped me .its working i think everytime i guess but i wonder why it was working most of the time before .i was thinking same that it can be because of string comparison to interger. Though tysm .you can answer question so i can accept your answer.

Comment: Glad that it helped!